# Updating Middle Table Laravel Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a table that holds the `'Officiant_id'` and `'awards_id'`

When a user edits their profile it will display in a checkbox all the available ones and auto check the ones that are on that table.

Although, now its time to update, let's say a user unselects one, how can I update the table to delete it, or if they check a new one add that new one to the table.

```
@if(!empty($officiant - > useraward))
@foreach($officiant - > useraward as $arr)
@php $removeId[] = $arr - > id @endphp {
    {
        Form::checkbox('awards[]', $arr - > id, true, ['class' => ''])
    }
} {
    {
        $arr - > name
    }
} {
    !!'<br>'!!
}
@endforeach
@endif

@php
$offaward = Info::officiantAwards();
foreach($removeId as $key) {
    unset($offaward[$key]);
}

@endphp

@foreach($offaward as $k => $v) {
    {
        Form::checkbox('awards[]', $k, false)
    }
} {
    {
        $v
    }
} {
    !!'<br>'!!
}
@endforeach

if (!empty($request - > awards)) {
    foreach($request - > awards as $i => $k) {
        $awards[] = $request - > $k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all awards as an array and call the `sync()` method on your `$officiant`.According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)/Syncing Associations

> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many
>   associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the
>   intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be
>   removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is
>   complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the
>   intermediate table:

So in your case after calling the `update()` or `save()`,

```
//get all award ids
$awards = $request->get('awards');

//save or update officient action

//updating relation
$officiant->awards()->sync($awards);
```